# Haskell how to get sum of all positive members using function composition?

Tags: haskell, function-composition

I have to write a function that takes all positive numbers from Integer list, adds to each 10 and then sums all of them until it reaches the maxNum.

I've already wrote something that kinda works :

```
ff :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Integer
ff maxNum = (<=maxNum) . sum . map(+10) . filter(>0)
```

but the problem is that this function returns true if the sum is not bigger than maxNum and false if sum is bigger... As I understand I am quite close to what I want.. Can someone help me???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a rolling sum, e.g. something like

```
rollingSum [1..10] = [0,1,3,6,10,15,21,28,36,45,55]
```

After all, `sum` will only give you the *final* sum, where you need to check the intermediate ones.

Luckily, `scanl (+) 0` provides this functionality. Therefore, you can take numbers of that rolling sum as long as they are smaller than `maxNum` and then the `last` element:

```
ff maxNum = last . takeWhile (<= maxNum) . scanl (+) 0 . map (+10) . filter (> 0)
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it should be... maybe you didn't understood my question... when I call my function whit these parameters "ff 26 [2, -3, 4]" I should get the result of value 26, because (2 + 10) + (4 + 10) <= 26.. Your approach just gives me last number increased by 10

Comment: @NikasŽalias it doesn't. `(\maxNum -> last . takeWhile (<= maxNum) . scanl (+) 0 . map (+10) . filter (> 0)) 26 [2,-3,4]` is 26. Did you really use `scanl` (__and__ `takeWhile`?)

Comment: sorry, my mistake, somehow haskell wrongly compiled, not everything is fine.. thank you!!!!!!